# Android: load custom font in SD card

Tags: android, resources, fonts, sd-card

Is it possible to use a custom font in android which is stored in the SD card? What I've seen so far indicates the font file must be in the assets folder. Please tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not tried it myself but the recipe states you might be able to do it by using the

```
Typeface.createFromFile(String path)
```

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=A2DD7A11C804B7C7646DCA883AA452FC?recipeId=1141

Answer (score 9):

`Typeface.createFromFile()` takes a `String` path or `File`.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "font.ttf"));
```